# set value to display information

Tags: php, cakephp

I have a piece of code I can't figure out how it actually works.
Its flow is like this, looks very easy

1. Get information to display for example `$info`
2. Display information using `$this->set('columnname', $info);`

Is that set function built-in in cakephp? `columnname` can also be page's content/type. this `set` will display info in the page. Where is that page source I need to see? For example perhaps it is stored somewhere in some view that has something like `<span id=x></span>` it then may only need to get the id and replace something inside the span.

Comment: Check this -> http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/view/979/set

Answer (score 0):

Yes **set** is built-in in cakephp.
You set variables from controller to pass it to view, like in your controller

```
$this->set("your_info", $info);
```

Then in view you can access it as:

```
echo "This is the info set from controller:".$your_info;
//or if its an array, do
print_r($your_info);
```

Did you mean something like that. Hope it helps